# How can I join a Hangouts call with Hangouts Meet?

Tags: google-hangouts

(The links provided by the Hangouts program do not work in Hangouts Meet - it appears I cannot enter the final character in the link, in either case it says "No such meeting.".)

Alternatively the answer to [a different question](https://superuser.com/questions/1351916/how-can-i-join-a-meeting-in-the-google-android-calendar-with-hangouts) could solve my issue.

Comment: It's quite hard to see what the problem is. Could you [edit] your question and describe more fully what steps you take in what apps, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: OK, I will see if I can schedule a meeting with myself to get some screen shots.